# How To Repeat Same Select Function On Multiple Datasets In R Then Divide Them By The Number Of Rows

Tags: r, database, select

So Basically I'm Trying To Find The % Of Items Containing A Certain Allergy In Food Products Then Divide It By The # Of Rows From That Specific Menu. Then Export it into a table.

This Is The Code I'm Doing Right Now And It's Extremely Repetitive.

```
Gluten1.Contain <- select(Arbys.Data, "Gluten") %>%
filter(Gluten == "YES") 

rows1<- nrow(Arbys.Data)

Gx1 <- c(count(Gluten1.Contain)/rows1)

Arbys<- as.character("Arbys")

x1<- c(Arbys,Gx1,Dx1,Ex1,Sx1,Px1,Tx1,Sfx1,Fx1,GDx1,GEx1,GSx1,GDEx1,
GESx1,GDSx1,GDESx1, DEx1, DSx1, DESx1, ESx1)

RP<-rbind.data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,
x14,x15,x16,x17, x18,x19,x20,x21,x22,x23,x24,x25,x26,x27,x28,x29,x30,
x31,x32,x33,x34,x35,x36,x37,x38,x39,x40,x41,x42,x43,x44,x45,x46,x47,
x48,x49,x50,x51,x52,x53,x54,x55,x56)

names(RP) < c("Restaurant","Gluten","Dairy","Egg","Soy","Peanut",
"Treenut", "Shellfish","Fish","GD","GE","GS","GDE","GES","GDS","GDES",
"DE", "DS","DES","ES")
```

The Letters Gx1 Dx1 etc stand for allergies and allergen combinations. d=dairy f=fish, etc.

As You Can See I'm Doing This For 19 Different Combinations. and 56 restaurants. This is incredibly repetitive and time-consuming. How Can I make This simpler?

Edit------------------------------------------------------------------

So I Made A Function That Can Do All The Work. How Can I Apply This Function To A List Of CSV Files In A Folder And Make It Release As A Data Frame

```
Data.Fun<- function(x) {

{ G <- select(x, "Gluten") %>%
filter(Gluten == "YES") }


 {D <- select(x, "Dairy") %>%
  filter(Dairy == "YES") }

 {E <- select(x, "Egg") %>%
  filter(Egg == "YES") }

 {S <- select(x, "Soybean") %>%
  filter(Soybean == "YES") }

 {P <- select(x, "Peanut") %>%
  filter(Peanut == "YES") }

 {Tn <- select(x, "Tree.Nuts") %>%
  filter(Tree.Nuts == "YES") }

  {Sf <- select(x, "Shellfish") %>%
  filter(Shellfish == "YES") }

  {Fi <- select(x, "Fish") %>%
  filter(Fish == "YES") }

  {GDx <- select(x, "Gluten", "Dairy") %>%
filter(Gluten == "YES", Dairy =="YES") }

  {GEx <- select(x, "Gluten", "Egg") %>%
filter(Gluten == "YES", Egg =="YES") }

  {GSx <- select(x, "Gluten", "Soybean") %>%
filter(Gluten == "YES", Soybean =="YES") }

  {GDEx <- select(x, "Gluten", "Dairy", "Egg") %>%
filter(Gluten == "YES", Dairy =="YES", Egg =="YES") }

  {GDSx <- select(x, "Gluten", "Dairy", "Soybean") %>%
filter(Gluten == "YES", Dairy =="YES", Soybean =="YES") }

  {GESx <- select(x, "Gluten", "Soybean", "Egg") %>%
filter(Gluten == "YES", Soybean =="YES", Egg =="YES") }

  {GDESx <- select(x, "Gluten", "Dairy", "Egg", "Soybean") %>%
filter(Gluten == "YES", Dairy =="YES", Egg == "YES", Soybean == "YES" ) }

  {DEx <- select(x, "Egg", "Dairy") %>%
filter(Egg == "YES", Dairy =="YES") }

  {DSx <- select(x, "Soybean", "Dairy") %>%
filter(Soybean == "YES", Dairy =="YES") }

  {DESx <- select(x, "Egg", "Dairy", "Soybean") %>%
filter(Egg == "YES", Dairy =="YES", Soybean == "YES")} 

  {ESx <- select(x, "Egg", "Soybean") %>%
filter(Egg == "YES", Soybean =="YES") }






  {Gluten <- count(G)/nrow(x)}
  {Dairy <- count(D)/nrow(x)}
  {Egg <- count(E)/nrow(x)}
  {Soy <- count(S)/nrow(x)}
  {Pnut <- count(P)/nrow(x)}
  {Tnut <- count (Tn)/nrow(x)}
  {ShellF <-count (Sf)/nrow(x)}
  {Fish <- count (Fi)/nrow(x)}
  {GD<- count(GDx)/nrow(x)}
  {GE<- count(GEx)/nrow(x)}
  {GS<- count(GSx)/nrow(x)}
  {GDE<- count(GDEx)/nrow(x)}
  {GDS <- count(GDSx)/nrow(x)}
  {GES <- count(GESx)/nrow(x)}
  {GDES <- count(GDESx)/nrow(x)}
  {DE <- count(DEx)/nrow(x)}
  {DS <- count(DSx)/nrow(x)}
  {DES <- count(DESx)/nrow(x)}
  {ES <- count(ESx)/nrow(x)}


  {data.vector <- c(Gluten, Dairy, Egg, Soy, Pnut, Tnut, ShellF, Fish, GD, GE, GS, GDE, GDS, GES, GDES, DE, DS, DES, ES)}

  {cbind.data.frame(data.vector)}

}
```

Comment: Holy title case. Please provide a data sample (what is inside `Arbys.Data`?) so that we can understand the actual sequence of events you are trying to carry out. Or use a built in dataset to illustrate.

Comment: The Data Is Basically | The Columns Are Food Allergies Like Gluten, Dairy, Egg, Ect and The Rows are YES and NO.